# number_to_human_size throws error in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filesize, null

In a view of my Rails app, I have a line:

```
<%= number_to_human_size(4871156, :precision => 3) %>
```

which gives `no implicit conversion of nil into String` error when other translations are selected other than english. But, the line

```
<%= number_to_human_size(487, :precision => 3) %>
```

gives

```
487 Bytes
```

Using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0. What could be the issue?

Thanks :)-

Answer (score 0):

It was due to improper/non specification of translations for locales other than english.

Please refer 
http://rorguide.blogspot.in/2011/03/i18nmissingtranslationdata-translation.html

That fixed it

I have added translation as per the above link and properly intended the locale variables inside the locale file. That made it correct. Thanks :)-

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the above error by adding the following line to **application.rb**:

**`ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root = ''`**

The error is most likely due to a bug in Rails version which is **3.2.13**.

Comment: Also some times it happens due to Devise gem version.

Comment: It was due to improper specification of translations for locales other than english. Please refer http://rorguide.blogspot.in/2011/03/i18nmissingtranslationdata-translation.html. That fixed it. Anyway, thanks for your help..